# Separate Datetime column while rounding the time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have a `datetime` column in SQL Server that I need to extract the time while rounding to 15 minute intervals.

I have got the time to round to the 15 minutes (last 15 minute increment, not the nearest, so it won't go forward) but I need to have the time separate from the date part of the field.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, MyDate) AS char(2)) + ':' + 
   CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, MyDate) / (24 * 4) AS CHAR(5)) as Interval2
```

Can anyone tell me how I can separate out the time from the date part of the column?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you've already done using DATEPART?

Comment: The above code gives me the results of 0:0 for the time.  It doesn't give me the format of 00:00 for example.  I have found code that gives me the rounding for the time but doesn't remove the date format and I need to have the date format removed: 'cast(round(floor(cast(MyDate as float(53))*24*4)/(24*4),5) as smalldatetime)AS Interval'

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 108)
```

This should give you the time only part from the datetime column i.e. hour:minute:seconds. Convert() function is usually a good way to go if you are just looking to get a datetime/date field in a certain format.

108 in the convert() function returns the datetime field in hh:mm:ss format. Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

You could create a function something like this where you could input your datetime field and roundto to 0.25 (that would be 15 minutes interval i.e. 60 minutes *0.25 = 15 minutes).

```
USE [DatabaseName] --replace with your db name
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float) RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime, @Multiplier float

    SET @Multiplier = 24.0 / @RoundTo

    SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar, @Time, 121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier, 0) / @Multiplier

    RETURN @RoundedTime
END
```

Then you could use the above function something like this to get your time only:

```
select convert(varchar(8),dbo.RoundTime(getdate(),0.25),108)
```

If above statement does not work for you, this should definitely work:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN convert(VARCHAR(8), dbo.RoundTime(getdate(), 0.25), 108) > convert(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 108)
            THEN convert(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(minute, - 15, dbo.RoundTime(getdate(), 0.25)), 108)
        ELSE convert(VARCHAR(8), dbo.RoundTime(getdate(), 0.25), 108)
        END new_time
```

Comment: Could you also explain your answer?

Comment: Sure, if you are interested in learning more about convert() function. This would be a good place to start: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: It's not for me. Your answer got stuck in a review queue of potentially "low quality questions". This is because of the the lack of explanation. It is always a good thing to explain the question, regardless of how trivial it seems to yourself.

Comment: Thanks Magnilex, I have added more description to my answer. Appreciate your feedback!

Comment: While this will display the datetime as  hh:mm:ss format it won't round the figures to the 15 minute interval that I need to do as well.

Comment: I have added an update to my initial answer. Please let me know if that works or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cast the data to the `time` datatype. A quick demo of how this might work:

```
DECLARE
  @TestD  datetime
 ,@TestT  time


SET @TestD = getdate()

SET @TestT = @TestD

PRINT @TestD
PRINT @TestT
PRINT '-------------------------'
PRINT CAST(@TestD as Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(ROUND(FLOOR(CAST(MyDate AS float(53)) * 24 * 4) / (24 * 4), 5) AS smalldatetime), 108))
```

I got this code and it extracts the time from the date time field and rounds the time to the quarterly interval which I was looking for.